# Set the Value of Dynamically Generated DIV input Fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

Dear Experts,
I am following [Mr.Steve Sanderson Example](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/validating-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) for working with variable length list, ASP.NET MVC 2-style.

In my Scenario I have one text box in which a user scan through a barcode scanner and the value of scanned barcode will distributed in variable list input fields.

I am using JQuery to set Values of those generated fields,

Example of dynamically Generated DIV is

```
<div class="editorRow">
<input type="hidden" name="gifts.index" autocomplete="off" value="a041d40e-d016-4543-b3f1-bf72239e1377" />

   Area Code <input id="gifts_a041d40e-d016-4543-b3f1-bf72239e1377__AreaCode" name="gifts[a041d40e-d016-4543-b3f1-bf72239e1377].AreaCode" type="text" value="0" /> 
   Account No: <input id="gifts_a041d40e-d016-4543-b3f1-bf72239e1377__ConsCode" name="gifts[a041d40e-d016-4543-b3f1-bf72239e1377].ConsCode" type="text" value="0" /> 
   Amount: <input id="gifts_a041d40e-d016-4543-b3f1-bf72239e1377__CAmount" name="gifts[a041d40e-d016-4543-b3f1-bf72239e1377].CAmount" type="text" value="0" /> 
   Coll No: <input Value="1" id="gifts_a041d40e-d016-4543-b3f1-bf72239e1377__CollNo" name="gifts[a041d40e-d016-4543-b3f1-bf72239e1377].CollNo" type="text" value="1" /> 
   <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>

    <span class="field-validation-valid" id="gifts_a041d40e-d016-4543-b3f1-bf72239e1377__AreaCode_validationMessage"></span>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" id="gifts_a041d40e-d016-4543-b3f1-bf72239e1377__ConsCode_validationMessage"></span>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" id="gifts_a041d40e-d016-4543-b3f1-bf72239e1377__CAmount_validationMessage"></span>
```

if you see there is one hidden field having index and value="a041d40e-d016-4543-b3f1-bf72239e1377" which is common in other members with their names. When I add one more DIV the hidden input value again change and all members of that div having the same common value.

I am stuck how to deal with it, so far I have successfully distributed the value of scan barcode to the input boxes which are out side of that dynamic DIVs like:

```
$("#ScanBCode").keyup(function (e) {
barCode = $("#ScanBCode").val();
if (barCode.length == 21) {
    var count = 1;
    Checking(count);
}

function Checking(count) {
    var code = barCode.substr(2, 3);
    var ACode = barCode.substr(5, 3);
    var Ccode = barCode.substr(8, 5);
    var Amount = barCode.substr(13, 8) / 1000;
    $("#TabACode").val(ACode);
    $("#TabCCode").val(Ccode);
    $("#TabAmount").val(Amount);
    $("#TabCollNo").val(code);
    $("#ScanBCode").val("");
}
```

});

Any Idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure wheter i got this one right, but it seems you're looking for a way to loop over a jquery collection, which can be done using [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

so instead of watching out for some generated IDs on your input field, i'd recommend looping over all of your generated 'fields', itentified by their class `editorRow`. just note that instead of having a separate id for each input field, you'd have to set some class on them, for example:

```
<div class="editorRow">
   <!-- set a class on your input fields -->
   Area Code <input class="areaCode" type="text" value="..." />
</div>
```

now you can apply the following javascript inside of your `keyup` handler:

```
$('.editorRow').each(function(){
  var $row = $(this);
  $('.areaCode', $row).val('somevalue');  //do this for all of your input fields
});
```

just post back in case something isn't clear here.

Comment: I want to vote up your answer but its required 15 reputation and I have only 5 now :(

Answer (score 0):

You are great its working fine my working code is,

```
$("#ScanBCode").keyup(function (e) {
    barCode = $("#ScanBCode").val();

    if (barCode.length == 21) {
        var code = barCode.substr(2, 3);
        var ACode = barCode.substr(5, 3);
        var Ccode = barCode.substr(8, 5);
        var Amount = barCode.substr(13, 8) / 1000;

        $('.editorRow').each(function () {
            var $row = $(this);
            var chk = $('.text-box-Area', $row).val();
            //alert(chk);
            if (chk == 0) {
                $('.text-box-Area', $row).val(ACode);
                $('.text-box-Cons', $row).val(Ccode);
                $('.text-box-coll', $row).val(code);
                $('.text-box-Amount', $row).val(Amount);
                $("#ScanBCode").val("");

            }
        });
    }

});
```